# MembershipUserCollection has some invalid arguments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

This code

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "validate[required]", disabled = "disabled", value = ViewBag.user[0].UserName }) @Html.ValidationMessage("usernameVal", "*")
```

trows an exception when it get to `ViewBag.user[0].UserName`

Exception:

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection.this[string]' has some invalid arguments

Action:

```
 public ActionResult EditUser()
    {

        //Resgata username do registro
        string user = Request.QueryString["username"];

        try 
        {   //Se nome foi resgatado
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(user)

                MembershipUserCollection muc = Membership.FindUsersByName(user);
                ViewBag.user = muc;


            return PartialView();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return Content("Erro: " + e);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, you are accessing the collection using the integer index

```
ViewBag.user[0]
```

As the Exception states, to access the MembershipUserCollection you need to provide a string argument.

See the documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection.item.aspx

*Gets the membership user in the collection referenced by the specified user name.*

Instead of returning a collection from your Controller method, just return the single MembershipUser object

**In your controller:**

```
        MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(user, false);
        ViewBag.user = membershipUser;
```

**In your view:**

Replace value = ViewBag.user[0].UserName with value = ViewBag.user.UserName

Comment: MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser("admin", false);
ViewBag.user = membershipUser; I still get nothing. No errors but no data either. And the admin users is there.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the collection is [expecting a string key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection.item.aspx) to access the elements not index.

You can try this

```
ViewBag.user.ElementAt(0).UserName
```

Alternatively if your are expecting one user object on your page then set `ViewBag.User` to that one user object and avoid looking for user at position 0